# Need app id and app secret for an existing facebook page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have spent much time googling and reading many articles over internet on this. But I couldn't link an existing page either to a new or existing app.

In a specific application page, under "App Details"->Contact Info->App Page, I go to a page where I can create a new page. I chose "Pages I Manage" on the top right and I was taken to the pages I already have. It has "login" button for each page. When I click the login button for the page I want to link with this app, It says "Sorry, something went wrong. Please try closing and re-opening your browser window."

I tried with many browsers and closing and then opening freshly.

Please help me in linking and existing page to an app and finding the app id and app secret for this page.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: You should just select one of your existing pages. The page needs to have the same name as the app and the app needs have the category app page

Comment: That Worked!
Thanks a lot WizKid!!

Comment: Hi WizKid, I am able to post the links to facebook page as a user. Instead I want to post as a page. I need access token of page. I couldn't find any article that posts the links to timeline as a page in facebook developer page.

I came across this article: https://www.sammyk.me/access-token-handling-best-practices-in-facebook-php-sdk-v4

But I couldn't even generate $session. Please guide me.

Thanks in advance!